# Need of Crystal (During UART Programming A Bare SI-Tiny-Gecko Chip)

Tags: microcontroller, serial, uart, crystal

I'm trying to set up a proper circuit for a bare chip (currently I  have [EFM32TG222F32](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/EFM32TG222.pdf) under my reach but I want to be able to work with any chip I get.) I'm setting up my circuit on a breadboard using a "QFP-to-DIP" adapter and proper capacitors, resistors, etc.

(I'm following the [Hardware Design Considerations](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN0002-efm32-and-ezr32-hardware-design-considerations.pdf) document that is released by Silicon Labs)

I'm using a USB-UART adapter to try to program the chip (using ".bin" docs generated by uVision).

(I'm following the [AN0003](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN0003.pdf) and [AN0042](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN0042.pdf) documents - also released by Silicon Labs)

Do I need an external crystal for my circuit?

If I decide to use a crystal, how I am going to find the proper values for the load capacitors that I need for connecting a crystal? (Values are not specified in datasheet or reference manual) (I'm planning to use a 24MHz or 8MHz crystal since those are the parts I own right now)

Comment: if you add links to the datasheets and other documents it would save people from having to go searching for them and possibly getting the wrong ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the AN0003 bootloader uses autobaud algorithm with the internal RC oscillator. Thus no external crystal is required for the UART bootloader to work.

> I'm setting up my circuit on a breadboard using a "QFP-to-DIP" adapter

Probably not a great idea, as your power supply traces could end up being too long. Decoupling capacitors need to be as close to the chip as possible,
as described in AN0002.

> how I am going to find the proper values for the load capacitors that I need for connecting a crystal

See AN0016: Oscillator Design Considerations. If you 24 or 8 MHz packages are not ultra-small SMD ones, `22 pF` load capacitors should work.

Comment: I am not linking those ANs, they can be accessed in [Simplicity Studio](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/simplicity-studio.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally missed the oscillator document. I can guess that the adapter thing is a bad idea, but that is probably the only way to try different kinds of chips. (I'm TOTALLY open for alternative ideas)

Answer (score 0):

For the load capacitors

https://community.nxp.com/thread/388856

In summary from the link

CL = Load capacitance (check the datasheet of your crystal)

Cstray = Stray capacitance, varies by layout but usually 2-5pF

2 load capacitors CX1 and CX2

CX1 = CX2 = 2(CL - Cstray)